# UIImage to MTLTexture when downloaded as PNG

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, metal

My use case is that a user takes a photo of themself on their phone, and uploads it to an image hosting service as a JPEG. Other uses can then download that image, and that image is then mapped to a metal texture for use in a game.

My issue is that if i download that image and simply display it in a UIImageView, it looks correct, but when I take the downloaded image and transform it into a metal texture it gets mirrored and rotated 90 degrees clockwise. I understand the image getting mirrored is due to metal having a different coordinate system but I don't understand the rotation issues. When I print the details for the image that has been passed into my function it has all the same orientation details as the UIImageView that is displaying correctly, so I have no idea where the issue is. Attached is my function that gives me my MTLTexture.

```
- (id<MTLTexture>) createTextureFromImage:(UIImage*) image device:(id<MTLDevice>) device
{
  image  =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]
                   scale:[image scale]
                   orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];

  NSLog(@"orientation and size and stuff %ld %f %f", (long)image.imageOrientation, image.size.width, image.size.height);

  CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

  size_t width = self.view.frame.size.width;
  size_t height = self.view.frame.size.height;

  size_t bitsPerComponent = CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef);
  size_t bitsPerPixel = CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(imageRef);

  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef);

  CGImageAlphaInfo alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

  //  NSLog(@"%@ %u", colorSpace, alphaInfo);

  CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | alphaInfo;
  //    NSLog(@"bitmap info %u", bitmapInfo);


  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( NULL, width, height, bitsPerComponent, (bitsPerPixel / 8) * width, colorSpace, bitmapInfo);

  if( !context )
  {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load image, probably an unsupported texture type");
    return nil;
  }




  CGContextDrawImage( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage);


  MTLPixelFormat format = MTLPixelFormatRGBA8Unorm;

  MTLTextureDescriptor *texDesc = [MTLTextureDescriptor texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat:format
                                                                                     width:width
                                                                                    height:height
                                                                                 mipmapped:NO];
  id<MTLTexture> texture = [device newTextureWithDescriptor:texDesc];

  [texture replaceRegion:MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
             mipmapLevel:0
               withBytes:CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
             bytesPerRow:4 * width];

  return texture;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Metal` coordinates are reversed. However, you now have a much simpler way to load textures with `MTKTextureLoader`:

```
import MetalKit

let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
let texture: MTLTexture = textureLoader.newTextureWithContentsOfURL(filePath, options: nil)
```

This will create a new `texture` for you with the appropriate coordinates using the image located at `filePath`. If you don't want to use a `NSURL` you also have the `newTextureWithData` and `newTextureWithCGImage` options.

Comment: Hollllly crap!. Thank you so much for this. Can you point me in the direction of the docs or wherever you learnt that?

Comment: sure thing. here is the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MetalKit/Reference/MTKFrameworkReference/index.html) and some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MetalKitEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) for the `MetalKit` texture loader.